# Embed the SSL certificate to iOS hybrid mobile app

Tags: objective-c, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have cordova based iOS mobile app which need SSL certificate to be embedded with the mobile app & using the AFNetworking plugin to achieve the same.

When I run the build, I am getting the error NSCURLConnection finished with error - code -1003.

Attached the code screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elact.png

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot I'd suggest changing that one line in the `if` statement as shown below.

```
if ( ... ) {
    manager.securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates = [NSSet setWithObject:localCertificate];
}
```

Note the warning - you are passing data to an ivar that should get a set.

Then based on the -1003 error - double check the URL that you use. Make sure it is valid and accessible.

**EDIT**

Also, add the following two lines just before the `if` statement.

```
manager.requestSerializer  = AFHTTPRequestSerializer.serializer;
manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer.serializer;
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error. It's cordova project. Using the cordova I am building for iOS. The SSL pinning is not happening.

Comment: I've edited the answer somewhat - see if it helps. If not I think you need to post a bit more of the actual code.

Comment: It didn't work. are you on skype? I can show you actual. My Skype ID: adarshsomasundar. Thank you in advance.

Comment: TCP Conn 0x283f31200 SSLHandshake failed (-9807) This is the error

Comment: Then I think maybe you need to check your certificate?

Comment: The same certificate is pinned for android app and it's working fine.

Comment: Detail screenshot for your ref: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBpSI.jpg

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed as I think the original problem has been solved and we are now dealing with a new problem related to your certificate. I suspect the solution could be to edit Info.plist but it may of course also be something else. Maybe post the relevant sections of your Info.plist as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224011/discussion-between-adarsh-somasundar-and-skaak).